# How to verify that files in A folder are also in B folder

Tags: find, diff, move, synology

I use my synology DS1515+ and DSM 6.2.2.

First of all, please refer to the picture as below;

[image]

First, I download some video files. Examples of filenames are as above.

And second step is that copying files to `/volume1/Daily/`

I've already solved it so far and there's no problem.

I'd like to solve the final step.

After copying files to `/volume1/Daily/`, I wanna move these video files to `/volume1/Temp/`

I think this sequence is important because

if these files move to `/volume1/Temp/` before copying, copying can't be executed.

So I think that it would be checked files are already copied to `/volume1/Daily/` (whether files are in the `/volume1/Daily/` directory or not) before moving to `/volume1/Temp/`.

In conclusion,

if video files were in `/volume1/Daily/`, I'd like to move files to `/volume1/Temp/`.

Could you help or explain how to do it?

It will be run the command only on the synology. (to use task scheduler in the control panel)

If you explain to me, please include path of directory in my case as above.

(because I can't apply the code what you recommend to me for lack of my understanding. I apologize)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would help ;

```
test -e /volume1/Daily/<file-name> && mv /volume1/Daily/<file-name> /volume1/Temp/<file-name>
```

Comment: @Freddy : yeah , thanks for notifying...

Comment: I think the source dir is `/volume1/download/` :)

Comment: @Freddy : No i think , once its downloaded in download directory , he is copying those into Daily directory , he needs to verify if its already in Daily directory then move it to temp directory ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved as below;

```
find "/volume1/Download/" -type f -printf "%f\n" | while read filename
do
if [ -f "/volume1/Daily/$filename" ] ; then
   mv "/volume1/Download/$filename" "/volume1/Temp/"
else
   echo "skip"
fi
done
```